# Getting strange filenames when cloning a repository using TortoiseGit

Tags: php, version-control, repository, tortoisegit

Hi I've been using Tortoise to clone a repository from a friends site - For some reason even though I can see all the files they are 0kb and all end in .i - so for instance index.php is now index.php.i

Can anyone explain what has happened with the clone - did I make a mistake on setting it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed : deleted & re-cloned and all seemed to work with the files.